# Help to solve rubik cube 3*3*3

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

[image: white]
[image: orange]
[image: blue]
[image: yellow]
[image: green]
[image: red]
How to solve my rubik? Which pattern left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your pictures, I found the orientation as below.

[image]

Keep the red face on top as below,

[image]

Then follow the below algorithm:

> L' U' L F -  L' U' L U -   L F' L$^2$  -  U  L U

L' - turn the left layer up

L - turn the left layer down

U - turn the top layer clockwise

U' - turn the top layer anti-clockwise

F - turn the front layer clockwise

F' - turn the front layer anti-clockwise

L $^2$ - turn the left layer twice (any sense doesn't affect the orientation)

Step 1

> L' U' L F

[image]

Step 2

> L' U' L U

[image]

Step 3

> L F' L $^2$

[image]

Step 4

> U L U

[image]

For simulation, (click the below link and click the play option)

https://alg.cubing.net/?scheme=custom&setup=z-yL-U-LFL-U-LULF-L2ULU&alg=L-U-LFL-U-LULF-L2ULU